# Gradle. Calling getProjectDir() returns not the dir that expected

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have subprojects in my Gradle project

So, In my `bulid.gradle` file I have code like this:

```
void getDir() {
    getProjectDir()
}

configure(project('SubProject')) {
    getDir()
}
```

So, now `getProjectDir()` inside `getDir()` returns `MainProject` dir, but I want this call to return `SubProject` dir.

Hope for your help, thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you even want to define a method inside your build script? I'm pretty sure there is a more Gradle-ish solution to your special use case.

Comment: Okay, ideally I want to have a method that receives relative path and some properties as map, and inside it resolves relative path depends on dir of project it called from and then creates this properties. Yeah, maybe there's more Gradle-ish solution, as you say, if you know such a feature I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided is part of the root project build script , so Gradle will execute with the main (root) Project instance as context: in this case , getProjectDir() call is deletaged to the root Project instance that's why you get MainProject directory returned.

I think that your method "getDir" should take a Project instance as parameter, then you could write something like:

```
void getDir(Project proj) {
    def dir =  proj.getProjectDir()
    println "Directory is : " + dir
}

configure(project('SubProject')) { proj ->
    getDir(proj)
}
```

EDIT

If you want to avoid passing the Project instance as parameter, then you can use Groovy Closer as a hack:

1) transform getDir method into a real Closure,

2) before calling the getDir closure from your configure method, set the target delegate object

Following code should work:

```
// a closure that invoke getProjectDir on the delegate Project
def getDir = { 
    println "project directory is: " + getProjectDir() 
}

configure(project('subproject')) { proj ->
    // set closure target delegate to SubProject instance 
    getDir.delegate = proj 
    getDir() 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I know about this solution, but in my case I wand to avoid passing project as parameter. Is there some hack how to do this without passing extra parameteres? Something like: change `getDir()` scope just inside, based on `Closure` `getDir()` was called from.

Comment: You could use Groovy Closure delegation feature as a hack, but this implìes that you rewrite your  "getDir()" method and transform it to a Closure . Then you will need to change the delegate of this closure before calling it, inside your configure block.    The following code should work:      `def getDir = {
    println "project directory is: " + getProjectDir()
}

configure(project('subproject')) { proj ->
    getDir.delegate = proj
    getDir()
}`